# Ruby on Rails is printing the JS to the screen when I have it respond

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Messing around with Ruby on Rails doing some hands on learning. I have reached a point where I would like for the form to submit and the controller to respond with JS. instead it prints the JS on the screen...

Messages Controller:

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @messages = Message.all
        @message = Message.new
    end

    def new
        @message = Message.new
    end

    def create 
        @message = Message.new(message_params) 
        if @message.save 
            @messages = Message.all
            @message = Message.new
            respond_to do |format|
                format.js {}
                end a
        else 
            render 'new' 
        end 
    end

    private 
        def message_params 
        params.require(:message).permit(:content) 
    end

end
```

Messages Page (HTML):

```
<div class="header">
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag "chat.css" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "jQuery.js" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "chat.js" %>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Messenger</h1>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="messages">
  <div id="messages_scroll" class="container">
    <% @messages.each do |message| %> 
        <div class="message"> 
          <p class="content"><%= message.content %></p> 
          <h6 class="time"><%= message.created_at %></h6> 
        </div> 
    <% end %>
  </div>

    <br>
    <%= form_for @message, :remote => true do |f| %>  
      <div class="field"> 
        <%= f.label :message %><br> 
        <%= f.text_area :content %> 
      </div> 
      <div class="actions"> 
        <%= f.submit "Create" %> 
      </div> 
    <% end %>
</div>
```

Create.js.erb:

```
$('#messages_scroll').html('\
    <% @messages.each do |message| %> \
        <div class="message"> \
            <p class="content"><%= message.content %></p> \
            <h6 class="time"><%= message.created_at %></h6> \
        </div> \
    <% end %>');
```

What happens when I submit a new message:
[image: JS Prints on Page]

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

**create.js.erb**

```
$('#messages_scroll').html("<%= j(render(@messages)) %>");
```

**_message.html.erb** *(in the same directory)*

```
<div class="message">
  <p class="content"><%= message.content %></p>
  <h6 class="time"><%= message.created_at %></h6>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! One step closer. Now getting Missing partial messages/_message with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:js, :html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:

Comment: Rename the partial to `_message.html.erb` and try again

Comment: Now it acts like the erb does not exist... It keeps redirecting to /messages and I have NOTHING telling it to. It does not execute any of the JS. I have tried alerts and consoles as well.

Comment: It's loading the messages directory because that's the convention. If you want a different directory, specify it in the render method and use the `collection` option for assigned the variable.  Read the rails docs and you will go far...

Comment: What I am trying to get it to do is to just stay where it is and reload the info in the messages div. Would it be best to just use standard ajax? Or is there a better practice in Ruby?